# Macro may not be enabled in this workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I am using `Excel 2007`. I am trying to play a game but when I started the game an alert message is displayed. The alert message is:

`Cannot run the macro *filename*. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.`

How do I enable `macros`?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I did not understand that alert message, I didn't try anything on my own. 
I don't know what is wrong with my question.

Comment: Nothing is wrong, I just wanted to find what you had tried, as after I search on Google for "how to enable macros excel 2007" I see the answer on the first result! Any way, pnuts has updated his answer to give you more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Developer Tab, Code, Macro Security and choose the right option.

You may need first to: in  Excel Options | Popular | Show Developer tab in the Ribbon.

The Excel Options button can be found just to the left of at the bottom right of the window that opens when the icon below is clicked (on the top left of the screen):

[image: SU536412 example]

Comment: There is no Options in Excel-2007.